# how to redirect URL containing query string and random numbers in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, query-string

When customers cancel a transaction on my site, they get redirected to the WooCommerce cart page with a query string containing randomly generated numbers at the end.

Example

```
https://www.example.com/cart/?woo-paypal-cancel=true&token=EC-5474842406066680S
```

(I need this redirect due to a plugin conflict between WP Rocket cache with CDN activated and WooCommerce. Long story.)

I'm wondering what exactly I would put in my `.htaccess` file to get it to redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/cart/
```

I've tried a number of variations I found on multiple pages here on Stackpath, but it wasn't redirecting. Obviously I'm missing something so I'm turning to the gurus.

Would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: You should show what you have tried. What's "Stackpath"?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/cart/?woo-paypal-cancel=true&token=<anything>` to `/cart/` you can try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^woo-paypal-cancel=true&token=
RewriteRule ^cart/$ /cart/? [R,L]
```

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* strips the query string from the request.

This is a temporary (302) redirect.